# How to return type of Stream of Objects with a Micronaut Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, repository, micronaut

I am trying to return a Stream instead of a Collection<> in a repository method written with the micronaut framework.

Documentation says this is supported and to do 2 things:

- Make the method transactional
- Execute this method within a try with resources statement

I have done both but I am still getting an error saying that the connection to the database is closed for some reason.
`org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl is closed`

This is my code:

Repository (JPA)

```
public interface ProductRepository<T extends ProductDataAccessObject> extends CrudRepository<T, UUID> {
    @Nonnull
    Stream<T> findByPriceBetween(double min, double max);
}
```

Class:

```
@Transactional
    protected void test(double min, double max) throws Exception {
        try (var products = this.products.findByPriceBetween(min, max)) {
            final var list = products.map(ProductDataAccessObject::entity).toList();
        }
    }
```

Note: I'm just trying it into a list just to see if it's working, but I will add the actual code on a forEach() method.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it make sense to define the method on the repository as transactional? Shouldn't the service method be transactional and then call the repo's method?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried adding the transactional annotation on the method that calls the repo's method too. Still seems to be getting the same exception.